# Control's parent is null when placed inside a ContentControl

Tags: wpf, silverlight, contentcontrol, transformtovisual

I've got a simple control derived from `ContentControl` with 3 properties.

My problem comes when I try to perform a control.TransformToVisual() with a control that is placed inside `MainContent`. It always brings up an `ArgumentNullException`.

My guess is this due to the control having a null Parent property. Is there a simple way to way around this?

## C#

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(LabelledControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidationContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ValidationContent", typeof(object), typeof(LabelledControl), null);

public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(object), typeof(LabelledControl), null);
```

### XAML

```
<Style TargetType="local:LabelledControl">
<Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:LabelledControl">

            <StackPanel Margin="0 10 0 0">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <dataInput:Label Content="{TemplateBinding LabelText}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" IsTabStop="False"/>
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding ValidationContent}" IsTabStop="False"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <ContentControl x:Name="_contentControl" Content="{TemplateBinding MainContent}" IsTabStop="False"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I have been having the same problem, did you ever find an answer?

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the [`ContentPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter(VS.95).aspx) class instead of the `ContentControl` class within your ControlTemplate to present those properties within the template? I am not sure if it is related to your ArgumentNullException, but typically the content of a `ContentControl` is exposed on the template via a `ContentPresenter`.

Since your control derives from `ContentControl` the `ContentPresenter` will automatically bind the Content and ContentTemplate properties for you to whatever the Content property is set to. You could also manually bind the Content property of the `ContentPresenter` to your ValidationContent property.

I am not sure why you are defining a MainContent property when the base `ContentControl` already gives you a Content property to use, maybe that is a second piece of content you are trying to expose.

Comment: ContentPresenter skips `Control` though, so I don't get any templating? MainContent could be turned into Content though, that's a refactor I was planning on later unless it's the problem here

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by ContentPresenter skips Control. ContentPresenter is essentially a placeholder for the Content object of the containing ContentControl. That is how you can control where the Content is placed in your ContentControl's template.